# Access the shell printout that resulted from the previous command

Tags: tcsh

I have to run a command that prints out a message in my shell, with a path to a file.

```
>> myCommand.py
>> outputs path to file
```

I'd like to know if this message is stored anywhere so that I can access the path and automate opening the file (instead of opening it by copying and pasting it in the shell)

Comment: It seems to me you are asking to access `stdout` in **history**   . AFAIK, it may be available but only as in that session as far back as your history is set.

To clarify are you asking something different than these examples? https://askubuntu.com/questions/758991/bash-shell-output-history-file-location

and

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863282/does-stdout-get-stored-somewhere-in-the-filesystem-or-in-memory

Answer (score 2):

I feel like this is probably a duplicate, but every question/answer I've found so far has been just different enough that I can't use it directly to answer your question.  At least not the question in its entirety.

The short answer is "No".  There's no automatic variable in tcsh, Bash, Zsh, or Fish (or any shell that I know of) that captures the standard output of the most recent command.  The shell doesn't know whether the command that you run is going to output a single line, multiple lines in a stream, or even perform terminal manipulation commands (think `vi`, `nano`, or any curses-based utility).  It could also be a memory issue, as the output from some commands can go on, and on, and on, and on, and ...

But there *are* ways to automate this.  If you know in advance that you want to view the resulting file that is referenced by the filename output by that command, you can use the shell's command substitution to do something like:

```
> less $(myCommand.py) # POSIX (Bash, Zsh) or
> less (myCommand.py) # Fish Shell
```

Of course, substitute whatever you use to open the file instead of `less`.

You can also capture the filename in a variable to be used:

```
> OUTFILE=$(myCommand.py)
> echo $OUTFILE
> less $OUTFILE
```

The variable can be named whatever you want, of course.

Or you can output the results *and* capture it to a variable:

```
> OUTFILE=$(myCommand.py | tee /dev/tty)
filename
> less $OUTFILE # views "filename"
```

Finally, there are some other pretty hacky solutions that you can view in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955577/automatically-capture-output-of-last-command-into-a-variable-using-bash) to do automatic capturing of every command, but each has its downside.